# Caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully when hosting flask app in apache(Redhat)

Tags: apache, flask, redhat, rhel

I am trying to host Flask app in Apache using RedHat server.My server here is offline server which wont having any internet. When im trying to restart Apache server using this command "sudo service httpd restart" im getting the below errors.

AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips mod_wsgi/4.6.2 Python/3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations

AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'

AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully.

providing config file below

```
<VirtualHost *:8006>
                ServerName XXXXXXXXX
                ServerAlias www.yourdomain.com
                ServerAdmin admin@admin
        WSGIDaemonProcess adfs user=wweb group=wweb processes=1 threads=1 display-name=%{GROUP}
                WSGIProcessGroup adfs
                WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                WSGIPassAuthorization On
                WSGIScriptAlias / /app/adfs/adfs.wsgi
                <Directory /app/adfs>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```